# Find Maximum of Array of Index/Match from Concatenated String

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Given the following table:

[image]

I would like the Actual Start to show the Preferred Start value, if the Depends column is empty (easy).

If the Depends column contains one or more comma-separated Id values, I would like to split on comma, look up the array of "Preferred Start" values based on the corresponding Id value, and then select the maximum value.

The following formula will correctly split the "Depends" cell:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Which can be verified, by using an array-valued MAX function (this returns "4"):

```
={MAX((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))}
```

However, what I really want to do is:

```
={MAX(INDEX(Table1[Preferred Start],MATCH((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),Table1[Id],0)))}
```

Somewhere along the way however, it loses the "arrayness", and simply returns the "Preferred Start" of the first Id number of the split (Id 3, 17 Jan 18).

Is what I'm trying to do even possible without resorting to VBA? I suspect I will run into a circular reference in actuality, since I really need to take the maximum of the "Actual Start" (adjusted for dependencies), to properly cascade a chain of dependent items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `INDEX`, it's reluctant to return an array without some co-ercion. Generically this should work

`=INDEX(range,N(IF(1,{array})))`

so that becomes the following with your specific scenario

`=MAX(INDEX(Table1[Preferred Start],N(IF(1,MATCH((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),Table1[Id],0)))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I assume that every row has a different ID number because the `MATCH` function will only find the first match for each ID

....or for a completely different approach you can use `AGGREGATE` function (and `SEARCH` instead of `FILTERXML`), which doesn't require "array entry" and would return the correct `MAX` even if IDs repeat, i.e.

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,Table1[Preferred Start]/SIGN(SEARCH(","&Table1[Id]&",",","&G6&",")),1)`

Comment: Thank you, both of these solutions work well, and have taught me some new techniques I can use. Yes, Id numbers will be unique, although the 2nd solution seems better, since FILTERXML may be expensive computationally? Outside scope of original q, but it's necessary to iterate over adjusted values of the [Actual Start] column multiple times to ensure dependency chains are honoured - I have this working by adding multiple sequential columns to the right, each referencing the one before - but this limits to max chain length N (where N is the number of columns) - can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: @Hoodlum - sorry I'm not really sure what you're asking - perhaps better to start a new question (with link to this one)....unless you can explain succinctly in fewer than 500 characters.......

Comment: Not a problem, will do. Comment format not the best for this :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the match to include the max in it:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Preferred Start],MATCH(MAX((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))),Table1[Id],0))
```

Enter as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thank you, but that will simply match the Preferred Date of the item with highest Id number in the "Depends" comma-separated list - if the Preferred Start for row with Id=3 is later than row with Id=4, then it will return the wrong value. It should return the maximum Preferred Start date of all matching rows, irrespective of the sequence of the comma-separated Id numbers